# May I say "she never would be" or it should it be "she would never be"?

Tags: adverb-placement

I have been reading a novel (Bad for You) for the last ten days. I had read something odd, which did not sound natural to me so I landed here to get some help on it.

> **Bad for You**
>
> I tried hard not to let the fact Linc had been her first at something
>   eat me alive. I wasn’t going to date her. I didn’t date, for starters.
>   I tried that once, and I sucked at it. But I didn’t like sharing her
>   either. She was mine. No, she wasn’t. She was my friend. Boundaries. I
>   needed some boundaries in my head. Blythe was my friend. She made me
>   happy. She was not mine. She **never would be** because I didn’t want
>   someone to be mine.

My question is, can we use *never* before *would* or *will*? Does
 it work the same way or does it have a completely different meaning here?

**Examples:**

> She **never would be** because I didn’t want someone to be mine.
>
> She **would never be** because I didn’t want someone to be mine.

Please check the above sentences and let me know both are fine or not?

Answer (score 7):

*Never* may either precede or follow a tensed auxiliary.

The ordinary position, as you know, is after the auxiliary.

> He will never agree.
> I have never liked sushi.
> She will never be mine.

But in parallel clauses like this, *never* is usually placed before the auxiliary; this throws the stress onto the auxiliary and thus emphasizes the contrast in tenses.

> He has not agreed, and he never **will** agree.
> She is not mine, and she never **will** be mine.
> I don't like sushi, and I never **have** liked sushi.

Note that the parallel clause need not occur in the same sentence; the speaker may ‘pick up’ a phrase to parallel in the previous sentence.

> **A:** John has never agreed to proposals of this sort.
> **B:** And he never **will** agree to them, trust me.

The displacement is not obligatory. When the second clause is full, *never* may occupy its normal place; in this case, *never* bears the stress.

> <sup>ok</sup>He has not agreed, and he will **never** agree.
> <sup>ok</sup>She is not mine, and she will **never** be mine.
> <sup>ok</sup>I don't like sushi, and I have **never** liked sushi.

But when the auxiliary stands alone, with what follows it (the complement and/or the main verb) ellipted, the *never* **must** precede the auxiliary.

> <sup>ok</sup>He has not agreed, and he never will. ... *but*
> <sup>∗</sup> He has not agreed, and he will never.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>She is not mine, and she never will be.<sup>†</sup> ... *but*
> <sup>∗</sup> She is not mine, and she will never be.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>I don't like sushi, and I never have. ... *but*
> <sup>∗</sup> I don't like sushi, and I have never.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  *marks a usage as unacceptable*

<sup>†</sup> Note that in clauses where the lexical verb is *be* acting as a copula (linking verb), the *be* **cannot** be ellipted; these are both ungrammatical:

> <sup>∗</sup> She is not mine, and she never will.
> <sup>∗</sup> She is not mine, and she will never.

But when the lexical verb is *be* without a complement, in the sense “exist, occur”, it **can** be ellipted, and the rules I describe above apply:

> <sup>ok</sup>This must not be, and it never will be.
> <sup>ok</sup>This must not be, and it will never be.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>This must not be, and it never will.
> <sup>∗</sup> This must not be, and it will never.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for your quick response. I am so sorry, I did not understand after this (When the complement is ellipted and the auxiliary stands alone (or followed only by be, in copulative clauses), the never must precede the auxiliary).Could you please explain it to me.

Comment: @user62015 I have rewritten; I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Oh. As implied earlier, I didn't really have time to digest your post fully last night (I figured in principle I'd be able to understand all the *ellipted complement / auxiliary* stuff, but it's not second nature to me). All I remember thinking is there's definitely *something* about the verb ***to be*** in certain "never" constructions that makes it work different to other verbs.